The y-axis values ​are overlapped in a plot
I have a problem with a matplotlib plot, where the values of y axis is overlapped.
The data are stored inside a pandas dataframe.
I plotted the data in this way.
plt.plot((np.arange(len(df_inj['nome']))/1000), df_inj['nome'])


I looked for a solution and I tryed something, but alway with a not good result.
For me it is enough have a fixed number of values between the max and min but it should be done in an automatic way.

Are your y-values strings? https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/faq.html#why-do-i-have-so-many-ticks-and-or-why-are-they-out-of-order

Would like to share how your data looks like?

I'm pretty sure that df_inj['nome'] contains strings. You have to convert those strings to numerical values otherwise Matplotlib shows an y-tick & y-ticklabels for each element of  df_inj['nome'] , hence the black blocs

This question is similar to: X-axis tick labels are too dense when drawing plots. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thank you all, df_inj['nome'] contained strings! So i followed the suggestion and I converted them to numeric! Solved!
